# Pass values from a pandas Series to PostgreSQL query using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, psycopg2

I have a column in a DataFrame that contains the ids of records I want to return from a query.

This is what I have so far:

```
query = """select * from frames where recording_id in (%d) """ % (data['recording_id'].values)
mydata = pandas.read_sql(query, db_conn)
```

This returns a type error:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not numpy.ndarray
```

so I also tried using `.tolist()` instead of `values` but I have the same problem.

What is the proper way to pass these values?

Comment: `",".join(list(data["recording_id"]))`

Comment: @JackManey I'm sorry but I'm not sure how to use your comment to help me. :(

Comment: You want a comma-separated list of the elements in your column. That's how you get it: via `",".join`.

Comment: @JackManey I think I understand. I am getting a type error: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, numpy.int64 found` but I think I can figure this out

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jack and some googling, I managed to figure out a solution:

```
query = """select * from frames where recording_id in (%d) """ % (','.join([str(i) for i in data['recording_id']]))
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injections as far as I understand.